# Ruby: Find the next timestamp

Tags: ruby, timestamp, scheduling

If I am given a specific time in `HH:mm` format like: `22:00`, how do I get the next timestamp when I can schedule this event.

For example:

If the current time is `22nd April 23:30`, it should give as `23rd April 22:00`(UTC format is ok, date written only for reference)

If the current time is `22nd April 18:00` it should give as `22nd April 22:00`

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'time'

✎ today_hour_x = DateTime.parse("22:00")
✎ today_hour_x + (today_hour_x - DateTime.now > 0 ? 0 : 1)
#⇒ #<DateTime: 2019-04-22T22:00:00+00:00 ...>
✎ today_hour_x = DateTime.parse("10:00")
✎ today_hour_x + (today_hour_x - DateTime.now > 0 ? 0 : 1)
#⇒ #<DateTime: 2019-04-23T10:00:00+00:00 ...>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hardcode 22, but as idea for more flexible approach:

```
require 'date'

def event_time(hour)
  now = Time.now
  tomorrow = Date._parse((Date.today + 1).to_s)
  now.hour < hour ? Time.new(now.year, now.month, now.day, hour) : Time.new(tomorrow[:year], tomorrow[:mon], tomorrow[:mday], hour)
end
```

My local time is now 22nd April 16:16. So for example:

```
event_time(15) # => 2019-04-23 15:00:00 +0300
event_time(22) # => 2019-04-22 22:00:00 +0300
```

In Rails you can also use `Date.tomorrow`, `Time.now + 1.day` and other pleasant things

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'date'

def event_time(time_str)
  t = DateTime.strptime(time_str, "%H:%M").to_time
  t >= Time.now ? t : t + 24*60*60
end

Time.now
  #=> 2019-04-22 12:13:57 -0700 
event_time("22:00")
  #=> 2019-04-22 22:00:00 +0000 
event_time("10:31")
  #=> 2019-04-23 10:31:00 +0000
```